# Why won't my objects change color?

Tags: rendering, materials

I'm new to blender, so sorry if the wording of this is kind of vague. The objects color won't change and It is the color of the background. Also In render mode, it appears as a silhouette and only shows the world bg color.
[[image: outline the sculpture is shown and the inside shows gray squares. Light gray background.][1]]

[image: Text]

Comment: please share your file          https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: That grid pattern on your object clearly tells that your object is transparent. Check your material settings if values like Transmission is set to 0 and Alpha to 1

Comment: The transmission is set to 0 and alpha to 1. Should they be something else?

Comment: Hi, it`s easier for us to spot the issue if you share your blend file, so please share it with the given link.  https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: No problem, if you are unable to share it through blend-exchange then please share it through google drive.         https://www.google.com/intl/en_in/drive/download/

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PVrgw4YXy5rUw7cmHsNeDGENxNafWioW/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @chance thank you so much :)

Comment: I rendered it and it turned out perfectly fine.  Have a look at it    https://drive.google.com/file/d/11yzQO6d9z1SHjTwgPo5CyDygBl5USyks/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I think my computer is the problem then. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Yeah probably that is the issue